# magento how to list most viewed product with the minimal price

Tags: php, magento

Hello I would like to know how to write php statement for executing some sql query.

For example: (list all product with minimal price)

```
$collection1 = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection1
->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
->addAttributeToFilter('attribute_set_id', 4)
->setOrder('created_at', 'desc')
->addMinimalPrice()
->addFinalPrice()
->addTaxPercents();
```

The sql query is this way:

```
SELECT `e`.*, `price_index`.`price`, `price_index`.`tax_class_id`, `price_index`.`final_price`,
IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) AS `minimal_price`, `price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`max_price`,
`price_index`.`tier_price` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS
`price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '1' AND
price_index.customer_group_id = 0 WHERE (`e`.`attribute_set_id` = '4') ORDER BY `e`.`created_at` desc
```

But i knew the following php statement can list most viewed product:

```
$collection2 = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection');
$collection2->addViewsCount();
```

Then, the sql query is this way:

```
SELECT COUNT(report_table_views.event_id) AS `views`, `e`.* FROM `report_event` AS `report_table_views`
INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` ON e.entity_id = report_table_views.object_id AND e.entity_type_id = 4
WHERE (report_table_views.event_type_id = 1) GROUP BY `e`.`entity_id` HAVING 
(COUNT(report_table_views.event_id) > 0) ORDER BY `views` DESC
```

I am thinking how to write php statement for combining the above two sql query, i want to show the result from the following sql query.

```
SELECT COUNT(report_table_views.event_id) AS `views`, `e`.*, `price_index`.`price`, `price_index`.`tax_class_id`,
`price_index`.`final_price`, IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, LEAST(price_index.min_price,
price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) AS `minimal_price`, `price_index`.`min_price`, 
`price_index`.`max_price`, `price_index`.`tier_price` FROM `report_event` AS `report_table_views` INNER JOIN 
`catalog_product_entity` AS `e` ON e.entity_id = report_table_views.object_id AND e.entity_type_id = 4  INNER JOIN
`catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = 
'1' AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0 WHERE (report_table_views.event_type_id = 1 AND `e`.`attribute_set_id` =
'4') GROUP BY `e`.`entity_id` HAVING (COUNT(report_table_views.event_id) > 0) ORDER BY `views` DESC
```

I thought that i can write the following php statement, but it is not working, maybe addViewsCount() is override whole sql statement.

```
$collection3 = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection');

$collection3
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addAttributeToFilter('attribute_set_id', 4)
->addOrderedQty()
->addMinimalPrice()
->addFinalPrice()
->addTaxPercents()
->addViewsCount();
```

Now, who can know how to write php statement for listing most viewed product with minimal price, and please forgive me that i have a trouble requirement that attribute set id must be 4 for all product entity. I know this question is very challenge as i have no idea to search such information from google. Please everyone to look in the problem. Thanks for every efforts.

Comment: I think these php statement is working. 

$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
 
$collection3 = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')->setStoreId($storeId);
 $collection3->addViewsCount();
 $collection3->addAttributeToFilter('attribute_set_id', 4);
 $collection3->addAttributeToSelect('*');
 $collection3->addStoreFilter($storeId);
 $collection3->addMinimalPrice();
 $collection3->addFinalPrice();
 $collection3->addTaxPercents();

Answer (score 4):

Try something like

```
$productCount = 5;

//Get Store ID

$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();      

// Get most viewed product collection

$products = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')     
    ->setStoreId($storeId)
    ->addStoreFilter($storeId)
    ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'price', 'minimal_price', 'small_image')) 
    ->addViewsCount()
    ->setPageSize($productCount);

Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')
        ->addVisibleFilterToCollection($products);
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')
        ->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($products);

print_r($products->getData());
```

Read more at :

- http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/14764/P15/
- http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-how-to-get-most-viewed-products/

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php $productCount = 5;
 $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId(); 
$products = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection') ->addAttributeToSelect('*') ->setStoreId($storeId) ->addStoreFilter($storeId) ->addViewsCount() ->setPageSize($productCount); Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status') ->addVisibleFilterToCollection($products); 
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility') ->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($products);
 print"<pre>";
 print_r($products); ?>
```